# Android JAVA HTTP GET Request - NetworkOnMainThreadException with NULL message

Tags: android, http, exception, get, null

I've got portion of code that gets data from the GPS and should save it back to the API.

```
try{ 

        String Lat = URLEncoder.encode(Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()), "UTF-8");
        String Lng = URLEncoder.encode(Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()), "UTF-8");

        String currentLocationText = "My current location is: " + "Lat = " + Lat + "Lng = " + Lng;

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, currentLocationText);

        String urlString = "http://api/?lat="+Lat+"&lng="+Lng;

          URL url = new URL(urlString);
          URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
          InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

          StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
          IOUtils.copy(is, writer, "UTF-8");
          String theString = writer.toString();

          Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Server response: ."+ theString);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Exception: "+ e.getMessage());
      }
```

However during the runtime I receive in Logs:

```
"Exception: null"
```

In my manifest file I've put the:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Sorry if it looks messy (exception handler), I am the PHP developer and that are my very first steps :).

How do I know what's the issue? Can I improve the Exception message to know  what's going on?

EDIT:
Got the stack trace

```
01-16 21:47:14.759: D/MyLocationListener(2041): Exception: null
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041): Stack trace: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1144)
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041):     at com.example.gps_tracker.MyLocationListener.onLocationChanged(MyLocationListener.java:44)
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:255)
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:184)
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:200)
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
01-16 21:47:14.784: D/MyLocationListener(2041):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I think I need to read that and fully understand that:
[How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: Log the full stack trace of the exception and/or step through your code with a debugger.

Comment: @MattBall Thanks. I still don't have the answer, but at least got some stuff to read about :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do all of networking tasks using async task. Currently, the way you do is blocking the ui thread which is not permitted. That's why you're getting the error.

Check out this about how to use AsyncTask: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Just to confirm. Followed the answer from that thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception 

Which says exactly what link you've provided and all problems gone.

Answer (score 1):

Use AsyncTask for get and post request on the web